# Stored procedure for adding an application user MS SQL 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, return-value

I am trying to write a stored procedure for one of the queries for adding users into a table. I am having difficulty capturing the return values during success and failure.

The username column in the User table is defined to have a unique constraint.

This is the outline of the stored procedure.
Stored Procedure Name: CreateUser

Parameters

@username varchar(64)

@firstname varchar(64)

@lastname varchar(64)

@MD5Password varchar(64)

@Access_Control int

Returns Identity, -1 if user already exists or (-@@ERROR) (Integer)

Below is the stored procedure that I have written but I can't seem to capture the return value part.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@username varchar(64) = NULL, 
@firstname varchar(64) = NULL,
@lastname varchar(64) = NULL,
@MD5Password varchar(255) = NULL,
@Access_Control int = -10
AS
DECLARE @return_code int
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([username], [firstname], [lastname], [password], [access_control]) VALUES (@username, @firstname, @lastname, @MD5Password, @Access_Control)
 IF(@@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'User with this name already exists. Username must be unique' + @@ERROR
        SET @return_code = -1
    END
 ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @return_code = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

RETURN @return_code

END
```

I want to set the return value to the Identity in case of success. -1 if the user already exists or to some Error Value if some internal error occurs. How can I capture this behavior in the stored procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been able to solve the problem. I have updated the stored procedure. May be there is a better way of doing it and I would appreciate if some one can highlight that. I will add the code for stored procedure again below.

Comment: I am unable to add new code since I would be answering it myself and I am not allowed to answer my question for at least 8 hours from asking the question. Once the 8 hours pass, I will add the answer to the question.